# How to inject using autowire byType in Dependency Injection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I am trying to inject using auto-wire byType but I can't able to inject a value. If a declare Engine Class beans also in car Class beans than it's work but if I make different beans file than it does not work.

**Car.java(pojo class)**

```
package com.meet.Spring.AutoWiredDI;

public class Car {
    private String CarName;
    private Engine engine;


    public String getCarName() {
        return CarName;
    }
    public void setCarName(String carName) {
        CarName = carName;
    }
    public Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }
    public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [CarName=" + CarName + ", engine=" + engine + "]";
    }
}
```

**Engine.java(POJO class)**

```
package com.meet.Spring.AutoWiredDI;

public class Engine {
    private String engineName;
    public Engine() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("Engine is Called");
    }

    public String getEngineName() {
        return engineName;
    }

    public void setEngineName(String engineName) {
        this.engineName = engineName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Engine [engineName=" + engineName + "]";
    }
}
```

**CarEngineRun.java(main class)**

```
package com.meet.Spring.AutoWiredDI;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class CarEngineRun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("CarAutoWire.xml");
        Car c=(Car)context.getBean("c");
        System.out.println(c.toString());
    }
}
```

**CarAutoWire.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="c" class="com.meet.Spring.AutoWiredDI.Car" autowire="byType">
        <property name="CarName" value="Audi"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**EnginAutoWired.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
      <bean id="Engine" class="com.meet.Spring.AutoWiredDI.Engine" autowire-candidate="true" >
        <property name="engineName" value="External Engine"></property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

**output** :- Car [CarName=Audi, engine=null]
**Expected Output** :- Car [CarName=Audi, engine=External Engine]

Comment: Why? You aren't loading the `EnginAutoWired.xml` so there is nothing to wire.

Comment: True, Thanks. My mistake